# Issue while converting HTML to JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a div which contains this:

```
<div id="hidLocsJsonForAutoComplete" style="display:none;">[{"id":1,"desc":"Amazon","name":"amazon"},{"id":2,"desc":"Apple Bees","name":"applebees"},{"id":3,"desc":"Babys r Us","name":"babysrus"},{"id":4,"desc":"Costco","name":"costco"},{"id":5,"desc":"Concord Produce","name":"concordproduce"},{"id":6,"desc":"Grocery Outlet","name":"groceryoutlet"},{"id":7,"desc":"New India Bazar","name":"newindiabazar"},{"id":8,"desc":"SubWay","name":"subway"},{"id":9,"desc":"Walmart","name":"walmart"}]</div>
```

and then in the script section I have this

```
var jsonLocs = $('#hidLocsJsonForAutoComplete').html();
```

Now, jsonLocs[0] is returning

```
[
```

instead of

```
{"id":1,"desc":"Amazon","name":"amazon"}
```

I understand jsonLocs is considered as string. But how do I get the the first Json object in this array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsonLocs contains a String object you need to parse the inner HTML as json.
Try this:

```
var jsonLocs = $.parseJSON($('#hidLocsJsonForAutoComplete').html());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery 1.4.1 or newer, you can use jQuery's inbuilt [`.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function:

```
var jsonLocs = $.parseJSON($('#hidLocsJsonForAutoComplete').html());
```

On older versions, you can just use eval (and expose yourself to potential security/etc issues by doing it wrong, but..):

```
var jsonLocs = eval('('+$('#hidLocsJsonForAutoComplete').html()+')');
```

Answer (score 1):

Never Mind, got the answer !! :)

```
var jsonLocs = eval($('#hidLocsJsonForAutoComplete').html());
```

Did the magic. But wondering if this is the most effecient/recommended way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `jsonLocs` is just a string, that's why when you index the first element, you're getting the first character of the string. What you need to do is [parse](http://www.json.org/js.html) the value of the HTML into a Javascript object, and then take the first element.

So, you will then need to do something like this:

```
var jsonLocs = JSON.parse($('#hidLocsJsonForAutoComplete').html());
```

And of course, for browsers that do not support native JSON parsing, you can use Douglas Crockford's [wonderful library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) (or use `eval` if you like to live dangerously).